# Print either a string or a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shuffle

This is my code:

```
from random import shuffle

def scramble(sentence):
   split = sentence.split()
   shuffle(split)
   return ' '.join(split)

for i in range(20):
    reply = ['hi',scramble('me too thanks')]
    print(reply)
```

I'm trying to print either a scrambled version of the sentence "me too thanks" or just simply "hi". What I end up getting is this:

```
['hi', 'me too thanks']
['hi', 'too thanks me']
['hi', 'thanks me too']
['hi', 'too thanks me']
['hi', 'me too thanks']
```

and so on. It's working as expected, but it's printing the brackets as a whole when I only want it to print one or the other. I've worked with other programs where this usually works, but this isn't for some reason. Sorry if this is not a good question, I'm relatively new to python.

Comment: How do you want it to choose which one to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax1234 solution works but is discarding the result of `scramble` 50% of the time. It also creates an unnecessary list to choose in. That's a waste of CPU power.

Just do:

```
for _ in range(20):
    print('hi' if random.randint(0,1) else scramble('me too thanks'))
```

It's a ternary expression to print one or the other string. The cool thing is that if `random.randint(0,1)` returns `1`, `scramble` isn't executed at all

If you have more cases, you could pick a *function* at random, so you're only executing the one you need, using `lambda` for instance:

```
for _ in range(20):
    reply = [lambda : 'hi',lambda:scramble('me too thanks'),lambda:'hello']
    print(random.choice(reply)())  # note the calling of the chosen function with ()
```

Comment: If I were to add more options what would I change?

Comment: the main goal is avoiding computing results that you'll throw away. You could replace the ternary by a list of  `elif`. Wait, I've got a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing exactly what it is told: print the result, which is a list. To display one or the other from the list, use `random.choice`:

```
for i in range(20):
   reply = ['hi',scramble('me too thanks')]
   print(random.choice(reply))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from numpy as np
def scramble(sentence):
   split = sentence.split()
   np.random.shuffle(split)
   return ' '.join(split)

for i in range(20):
    reply = ['hi',scramble('me too thanks')]
    print(np.random.choice(reply))
```

Comment: it's exactly the same answer as Ajax1234 one, with numpy instead of classic random. What's the point?